# Вывод информации из Python в PDF

Tags: python, pdf

Необходимо вывести, например, какой-нибудь `print()` в PDF. В Python это выглядело бы так:

```
print("Овцы переходили через реку. Названия овец:\n", df.head())

out[]:
Овцы переходили через реку. Названия овец:
1. Стёпа
2. Феня
3. ...
```

Интересно увидеть решение, которое будет использовать библиотеки не требующие внешнего установочного вмешательства (wkhtmltopdf, buildtools)

Работаю под виндой, поэтому нет возможности использовать `sudo apt-get`, чтобы выполнить это через `wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: а установить бинарник религия не позволяет? https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Comment: конечно, она самая)